# Optimising Graph Vertex Value Assignment for Minimum Weights

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I have a real world problem that can be modelled as a graph. I'm looking for algorithms that can solve the general problem, probably as a graph or by linear programming.

I have a system that can be thought of as a highly connected <s>undirected</s> directed graph. Every vertex connects to every other vertex *in both directions*. I have a fixed set of values that can be assigned to a vertex. It is possible for the vertex value to be null. The number of values will always be <= to the number of vertices. There is a real-world physical distance between the locations of each vertex. The weight of an edge depends on the physical separation distance and the values assigned to the vertices at each end of the edge.

I am interested in finding the optimum assignment of values to vertices that minimises the weight of all the edges. I don't want to minimise the average of the edges in case the result is skewed by a wide variance of weights. I think I want to optimise for the minimum highest weight, but would be open to suggestions. The method for calculating the weights could probably be reworked if the problem were easier to solve as optimising for a maximum. If there are multiple optimum solutions, it is OK for my purposes to just find one of them.

In the real world case, it is possible for two vertices to have the same assigned value. In this case, some different constraints apply and we don't need to include it in the optimisation. I can ignore this complication if it simplifies solving the problem.

Are there any pre-existing algorithms or methodologies for solving this type of problem?

Comment: What is the explicit formula for the weight of an edge as a function of the distance and values assigned to the endpoints?

Comment: @RobPratt It might be difficult to provide the explicit weight formula. The real world system is a collection of antennas transmitting and receiving radio frequencies. The weighting is essentially the received signal strength at one antenna from a transmission at another antenna. The received signal strength is a function of the transmission power (constant for each assigned value), the free space path loss between the antennas (close enough to constant based on distance) and the receiver selectivity (proportional to difference between the assigned values & linear on a logarithmic scale).

Comment: Is it $d_{i,j} \exp(k|x_i-x_j|)$, where $d$ is the distance, $k$ is a proportionality constant, and $x$ is the assigned value to be decided?

Comment: @RobPratt I might have been misleading when I said when I said linear on a logarithmic scale. The unit of received signal strength is itself logarithmic, so that simplifies the calculation somewhat. I haven't worked out the weight formula exactly at this stage, but it must be in the form:
$$
W_{i,j} = P_i - ad_{i,j}^2 - b|{x_i - x_j}|
$$
Where $P$ is the transmission power, $a$ is a constant relating to the propagation characteristics through free space, $d$ is the distance, $b$ is a constant representing the reception characteristics and $x$ is the assigned value to be decided

Comment: Writing the above weight formula also made me realise that the problem is a directed graph, not undirected.

Comment: Are $P_i$, $a$, and $b$ positive constants?

Answer (score 1):

Let binary decision variable $y_{i,v}$ indicate whether $x_i=v$.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
z &\ge P_i - a d_{i,j}^2 - b \sum_{v_i, v_j} |v_i-v_j| y_{i,v_i} y_{j,v_j} &&\text{for all $i,j$} \tag1 \\
\sum_v y_{i,v} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2 \\
\sum_v v y_{i,v} &= x_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag3 \\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $z \ge \max_{i,j} W_{i,j}$.
Constraint $(2)$ assigns exactly one value to each node.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $y_{i,v}=1 \iff x_i=v$.

You can linearize the quadratic constraint $(1)$ by replacing the product $y_{i,v_i} y_{j,v_j}$ with binary variable $u_{i,v_i,j,v_j}$ and linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{v_i} u_{i,v_i,j,v_j} &= y_{j,v_j} &&\text{for all $i,j,v_j$} \tag4 \\
u_{i,v_i,j,v_j} &\le y_{i,v_i} &&\text{for all $i,v_i,j,v_j$} \tag5 \\
\end{align}